# ANT + propertyregex problem

Tags: java, regex, ant

I have the following string in a condition: 10.13.0.90:7000

I would like to extract it into two conditions, for example 10.13.0.90 and 7000.

I tried 
`<propertyregex property="client.ip" input="${client.address}" regexp="[0-9.]*:[0-9]*" select="\1" />` but this doesn't work. The conditions are pretty sure correct. Any suggestions?

Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use parenthesis to capture the group you refer to with "\1", e.g.

```
regexp="([0-9.]*):[0-9]*"
```

BTW, you could express digits using `\d` rather than `[0-9]`, e.g.

```
regexp="(\d.*):\d*"
```

Answer (score 3):

`\1` indicates the first grouping. but you did not group`()` at all.

Try this:

```
<propertyregex property="client.ip" input="${client.address}" 
regexp="([0-9\.]*):[0-9]*" select="\1" />
```